# log4net - database or file on disk

Tags: asp.net, log4net

Is it considered best practice to use file appenders or database appenders in log4net?

This is in a web farm environment hence I'm finding it a struggle managing multiple files for multiple sites - is the database a better way to go, and if so, are there any issues?

I've seen some people complain of connection pooling issues for example

My environment is MVC + NHibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BY default logging is not asynchronous. Logging to a database is much more expensive than logging to files, but the beauty of Log4Net is you can start with one store and switch if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd contend the best choice is what works in your environment, which seems to be database given the farm.

Beauty of log4net is this is all just a configuration switch so switching back to files after the database don't help isn't painful nor expensive. You can even log to multiple things if you so choose -- eg, trace debug stuff locally, auditing events go to the db and "the server is down" goes to some admin's email address.

Comment: Does that mean there are no negative side effects of using a database appender? For example, is all logging asynchronous and are there any issues with the frequency of logging/buffer size?

Comment: There are positive and negative side effects with everything in software [and life]. Find the pattern that fits your app . . .

Answer (score 0):

or a shared file system and write a file (assuming your web farm is all part of the same company)

.. the other thing that you can do is a hybrid strategy, where you write detailed data to a file, and summary (perhaps INFO level and above) to a network socket